# GlassFish 4 server not starting

Tags: java, glassfish-4

I am unable to start glassfish server 4 though when I had installed it worked smoothly
 and in the console following error comes up

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
ERROR: Error creating bundle cache. (java.lang.Exception: Unable to create bundle cache lock file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\cache.lock (Access is denied))
java.lang.Exception: Unable to create bundle cache lock file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\cache.lock (Access is denied)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.<init>(BundleCache.java:168)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:640)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:88)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error creating bundle cache.
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:90)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error creating bundle cache.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:645)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.run(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to create bundle cache lock file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\cache.lock (Access is denied)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.<init>(BundleCache.java:168)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:640)
    ... 1 more
```

The cache.lock file is of size 0 kbs am unable to understand why its showing me lock problem though I can access it

Comment: It is the server that is denied access, not you. Have you tried stopping the server, removing the file and then starting the server again?

Comment: which file r u talking about?

Comment: Delete the file cache.lock

Comment: well got the resolution :) provided admin access y d hell in my system its by default

Comment: You might wish to provide an answer to your own question then.

Comment: Well I provided administration access to the folder of felix it worked like charm :)

Comment: For those who use Linux: just run `sudo ./asadmin start-domain`.

Answer (score 1):

Change permissions on the glassfish folder on Windows.

--Go to Properties, then Security --> Change permissions.

Start again the glassfish.

Cheers